# Выравнивание по краю экрана в Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, bootstrap, адаптивная-верстка

Здравствуйте!

Недавно начал знакомство с Bootstrap и столкнулся с ситуацией, где в div'е размещается 2 блока: один с текстом, другой с изображением. Но загвоздка в том, что изображение должно прилипать не к краю контейнера, а к краю экрана. На просторах сети такого решения найти не смог, к сожалению.

Как это можно логичнее реализовать?

Макет:
[image: макет]

Я делал это как-то так:

```css
.collections-grey {
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
}
.collections-text-left {
  float: left;
}
.collections-text-right {
  float: right;
}
.collections-image-right {
  float: right;
}
.collections-image-left {
  float: left;
}
.collections-image-right img {
  width: 100%;
}
.collections-white {
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<section class="collections">
  <div class="collections-grey">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="collections-text-left">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
          </div>
          <!--collections-text-left-->
          <div class="collections-image-right">
            <img class="wow slideInRight" src="images/clips.png">
          </div>
          <!--collections-image-right-->
          <div style="clear: both;"></div>
        </div>
        <!--col-md-12-->
      </div>
      <!--row-->
    </div>
    <!--container-->
  </div>
  <!--collections-grey-->
</section>
```

Сразу прошу извинить за, вероятно, кривое сообщение, чукча только учится)

Comment: К краю экрана в смысле absolute и float:right? Нарисуйте макет и поможем.

Comment: Добавил макет и то, что натворил сам. Т.е. контейнер - там где начало и конец текстовых блоков, а изображения выходят за его границы и располагаются вплотную к краю экрана.

Answer (score 1):

Решение по вашему вопросу:

```css
.section-with-image {
  min-height: 150px;
  position: relative;
}

@media (max-width: 479px) {
  .section-with-image > img {
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 480px) {
  .section-with-image > img {
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: auto;
  }  

  .section-with-image > .img-left {
    left: 0;
  }

  .section-with-image > .img-right {
    right: 0;
  }
}

.section-with-image h2,
.section-with-image p {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.section-with-image a {
  margin: 40px 0;
}

.section-grey {
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
}

.section-white {
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<section class="section-with-image section-grey">
  <img class="img-right"
       src="http://i.gyazo.com/650a46387fa5db34470afd0a8984bd0b.png"
       width="414"
       height="265"
       alt="Clips"/>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <h2>Clips</h2>
        <p>Коллекция весна-лето 2016</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">Смотреть</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="section-with-image section-white">
  <img class="img-left"
       src="http://i.gyazo.com/4395a87eccc44866a1d4667e68735cba.png"
       width="369"
       height="213"
       alt="Brunella"/>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-6 text-right">
        <h2>Brunella</h2> 
        <p>Коллекция весна 2016</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">Смотреть</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="section-with-image section-grey">
  <img class="img-right"
       src="http://i.gyazo.com/650a46387fa5db34470afd0a8984bd0b.png"
       width="414"
       height="265"
       alt="Clips"/>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <h2>Clips</h2>
        <p>Коллекция весна-лето 2016</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">Смотреть</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

[Или посмотреть код на jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gambala/uw8yhwrj/)

Судя по вашим скриншотам - текст должен был прилеплен к краям контейнера. Это важное условие, так как в таком случае использовать `.container-fluid` уже не удастся. Однако можно использовать `.container` для контента, и абсолютное позиционирование по секции для изображения.

```
@media (min-width: 480px) {
  .section-with-image > img {
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: auto;
  }  

  .section-with-image > .img-left {
    left: 0;
  }

  .section-with-image > .img-right {
    right: 0;
  }
}
```

Обратите внимание на @media запрос - на узких экранах, чтобы контент не наслаивался на изображение - мы располагаем изображение над контентом:

```
@media (max-width: 479px) {
  .section-with-image > img {
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

В некоторых ситуациях решается так:

```
.slideInRight{
   position: absolute;
   width: N%;
   right: 0;
}
```

дальше уже с учетом занчения `width` можно изменить размер внутри контейнера, марджинами изменить высоту если надо.

Answer (score 0):

1. используйте не `.container` класс, а `.container-fluid`.
2. добавьте css свойство:

   ```
    .collections-grey .container-fluid {
       margin: 0 -15px 0 0;
    }
   ```

Comment: Если сделать так - текст не будет выровнен по границе контейнера

Answer (score 0):

Бутстрап предлагает иерархию [Контейнер > Ряды > Столбцы](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-intro). Можно взять её за основу и сделать, например, так:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<style>
  .collections-grey {
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
  }
  .collections-white {
    background-color: #fff;
  }
  .collections-image-left,
  .collections-image-right,
  .collections-text-left,
  .collections-text-right {
    padding: 0;
  }
  .collections-image-right,
  .collections-text-right {
    text-align: right;
  }
  .collections img {
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
</style>

<section class="collections">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row collections-grey">
      <div class="col-xs-7 col-xs-offset-1 collections-text-left">
        <h2>CLIPS</h2> 
      </div><!--col-->
      <div class="col-xs-4 collections-image-right">
        <img class="wow slideInRight" src="https://i.gyazo.com/650a46387fa5db34470afd0a8984bd0b.png" width="414" height="265" alt="CLIPS">
      </div><!--col-->
    </div><!--row-->
    <div class="row collections-white">
      <div class="col-xs-4 collections-image-left">
        <img class="wow slideInLeft" src="https://i.gyazo.com/4395a87eccc44866a1d4667e68735cba.png" width="369" height="213" alt="BRUNELLA">
      </div><!--col-->
      <div class="col-xs-7 collections-text-right">
        <h2>BRUNELLA</h2> 
      </div><!--col-->
    </div><!--row-->
  </div><!--container-fluid-->
</section>
```